# Why do 'floor ans*ans' and 'ceil ans*ans' (without any value assigned to ans) give a matrix output?

Tags: matlab

I have been messing around in Matlab and had the same outputs when I entered the following statements in the command window:

```
>> floor ans*ans

ans =  97   110   115    42    97   110   115

>> ceil ans*ans

ans =  97   110   115    42    97   110   115
```

I couldn't find any reference about this on the documentation page.

Answer (score 7):

There are [two ways](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) of calling a Matlab function.

Function syntax uses parentheses like this and is most general, passing arguments by value:

```
[out1, out2] = funcname(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

In command syntax, there are no parentheses, the arguments are separated by spaces, and the arguments are assumed to be strings (row vectors containing character values).

```
save mydata.mat x y z
```

You used command syntax for a function not meant to be used as a command. So Matlab passes a string to `floor` or `ceil`, the function forces the argument to convert to a numeric matrix, and then the function doesn't further modify those values since they're already integers.

The ASCII values of the characters in the string `'ans*ans'` are, guess what, `[ 97, 110, 115, 42, 97, 110, 115 ]`.